# How to give value form array to div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I have array with coordinates and also the same amount div.Now I need to first value from array to gave first div and so on.

And here is example of arrays

```
var xList = [265, 152, 364]
var yList = [125, 452, 215]
```

There is three values in every array as is three div

```
<div class"box">Box</div>
<div class"box">Box</div>
<div class"box">Box</div>
```

How to first value gave to first div second to the second div and so on.

And I was thinking about using css like this.

```
$(".box").css({ top: yList + "px", left: xList + "px" });
```

I tried to use for loop like here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < xList.length && i < yList.length; i++) {
        box.style.top = yList[i] + "px";
        box.style.left = xList[i] + "px";
    }
```

But it did not work.
This is just example it is not my real code except this for loop.This example is similar to my real code I have same amount of div as values in array and I need to give to first div first value second div second value and so on.
My all code is on  this link https://jsfiddle.net/SutonJ/5gyqexhj/35/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the supplied examples, you're not differentiating between the three different objects of class "box".  I expect you'll find jQuery's each() method useful:

```
$(".box").each(function(index) {
   $(this).css({top: yList[index] + "px", left: xList[index] + "px"}) );
});
```

... as documented here: https://api.jquery.com/each/